# Can the intersection of two balls be described?

Tags: spherical-geometry

Suppose, two spheres intersect. Subtracting the equations of the speheres, a linear equation appears which indicates the plane conataining all points belonging
to the intersection of the spheres.

But the intersection is only a small part of this plane.

- Can this intersection be described ? Do the points form a well-known
  geometric shape ?

Comment: Yes, I edited the qeustion.

Comment: just intersect the plane with either of the spheres

Comment: I do not want to calculate the intersecting points. I want to know if the intersection can be visualized.

Comment: Working in Cartestian coordinates,   suppose you have 2 spheres lying in $\mathbb{R}^3$:  $(x-a_i)^2 + (y-b_i)^2 + (z-c_i)^2 = r_i^2,$ where $i=1,2.$    Expanding the square terms, and subtracting  you see the intersection lies in a plane.   However, the actual intersection is a circle that happens to lie in the plane generated above.  See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sphere-SphereIntersection.html

Comment: Intuitively, if you're convinced that their intersection lies on a plane, is it a much greater leap to intuitively believe that the intersection must be circular, as that's the only way a plane can intersect a sphere?

Comment: The intersection of $F(x,y,z)=0$ and $G(x,y,z)=0$ can be written as $(F(x,y,z))^2+(G(x,y,z))^2=0$. The union can be written as $(F(x,y,z))(G(x,y,z))=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always choose a coordinate system such that the first sphere is the larger one (if radii differ) and is centered around the origin:
$$
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = R^2 \quad (*)
$$
and that the second sphere is centered around $(0,0, h)$:
$$
x^2 + y^2 + (z - h)^2 = r^2 \quad (**)
$$
for an intersection we should have $h \le R + r$.

For the intersection both equations $(*)$ and $(**)$ must hold. Substracting $(*)$ from $(**)$ we get:

$$
-2zh+h^2 = r^2-R^2 \\
z = \frac{h^2 + R^2 - r^2}{2h} =: z_i
$$

The equation $(*)$ then reduces to
$$
x^2 + y^2 = R^2 - z_i^2 = r_i^2 \quad (\#)
$$
with
$$
r_i = \sqrt{R^2 - z_i^2} 
$$
The equation $(\#)$ of the intersection is the equation of a circle with radius $r_i$.